# When do I add the chicken stock in this recipe? The author doesn't specify

Tags: sauce

I've found a bunch of morels this weekend and wanted to make a simple sauce with them.  The simplest one I want to try directs me to cook a medium shallot in butter until translucent, then add morels and a pinch of salt stirring occasionally for 3 minutes.  Follow this with 1/2 cup of white wine and reduce by two thirds.  Finally add heavy cream and simmer for 20 minutes until the sauce coats a spoon.

However the ingredients list also includes chicken stock, but there is no mention of it in the directions.  When would be the right time to add the stock?

Comment: Morels, you lucky devil! I don't like most mushrooms but morels are a different story!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the wine.

Let the wine *almost* reduce, then add the stock. Follow the recipe then from "reduce by two thirds", reducing the now wine-flavored stock.

You might as well be quoting any of 1000 recipes for mushroom risotto. It's basically a typo, the author has seen it so many times before that he doesn't see it.

I can't know *exactly* the author's intentions, but I'd bet my bottom dollar that those are pretty close.

Comment: That seems like the right order.  Thank you!  The author recommends serving the sauce with chicken breasts, but I plan to include linguini.

Comment: @FrankGallagher That sounds great!